# App stuck at Splash screen even after enabling internet connection

Tags: android, android-intent, splash-screen

I set my splash activity to check for active internet connection. If there is no internet connection, I've set an alert dialog to pop along with a button to open internet settings. Now the issue i face is that even after enabling internet connection and going bac, it is stuck in splash screen. App doesn't open the new activity.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    boolean mobileNwInfo;
    ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {     
          mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();   
      }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {     
          mobileNwInfo = false;
      }
    if (!mobileNwInfo) {
        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Info ")
                .setCustomImage(R.mipmap.alert)
                .setContentText("No internet connection!")
                .setConfirmText("OPEN SETTINGS")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                    }
                }).show();
    }
    else
    {
      Splash();
    }
}

public void Splash()
{
    int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the internet connection in onResume()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check internet condition in **onResume()**. Try below code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!checkInternet()) {
            new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE)
                    .setTitleText("Info ")
                    .setCustomImage(R.mipmap.alert)
                    .setContentText("No internet connection!")
                    .setConfirmText("OPEN SETTINGS")
                    .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                            sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Splash();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkInternet() {
        boolean mobileNwInfo;
        ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            mobileNwInfo = false;
        }
        return mobileNwInfo;
    }

    public void Splash() {
        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this code, alert dialog is always open even is there is active internet connection.

Comment: change if condition **if (!checkInternet())**, check my updated code.

Comment: Now that works perfectly. After enabling internet and going back splash activity runs again and opens the new activity. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure, need to wait 15 mins before accepting answer :)

Comment: OK. Have a nice day!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128226/discussion-between-sagar-zala-and-abhilash-murali).

Answer (score 1):

just paste this code in onStart() and remove else
    block from onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
void onStart()
{
    boolean mobileNwInfo;
    ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try { 
           mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected(); 
        }catch (NullPointerException e) { mobileNwInfo = false; }


if (mobileNwInfo) {

  Splash();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

boolean mobileNwInfo;
ConnectivityManager conxMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try { 
   mobileNwInfo = conxMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected(); 
    }
catch (NullPointerException e) { mobileNwInfo = false; }
if (!mobileNwInfo) {
    new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING _TYPE)
            .setTitleText("Info ")
            .setCustomImage(R.mipmap.alert)
            .setContentText("No internet connection!")
            .setConfirmText("OPEN SETTINGS")
            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                }
            })
            .show();
}
else
{
  Splash();
}


}

  public void Splash()
 {
int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

  }
```

Add this in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```